# MS Outlook Add-In: During "Compose Message" how does one separate previous conversation from newly composed?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

I'm setting up a MS Outlook Add-In that performs some analysis on newly composed messages. To read the message body, I use the    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync() function that's part of the outlook JS API. If the user is composing a message that's part of a conversation, i.e. when replying or forwarding, this will also yield messages that are part of that conversation. I want to remove previous messages from the returned body, since they are not relevant for the analysis. What is the best way to do this?

What I've come up with is a regex that matches common Conversation headers, specifically "From: ..... abc@def.gh" or similar.
The specific Regex I used:

```
/((From|Von|De|Desde).+)[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.+/g
```

I am aware that this will yield many false positives, so I am looking for a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Using the body.getAsync API on the newly composed message, you get the body of the current message itself and not the body of all the previous messages. But if you expand the message by clicking the "..."(Ellipsis button) in the mail, body returns all the messages of the previous conversations.

Comment: This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing request https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34344190-body-getasync-return-only-current-content-in-com. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, I cannot control whether users will expand the message. I have voted on the issue and I look forward to seeing it implemented in the future.